# How to derive the support function for this set?

Tags: convex-analysis

I want to ask how to derive the support function of the convex set (in $\mathbb{R}^2$) that is described as the intersection of

$x_1\leq \frac{3}{4}$,
$x_2\leq \frac{3}{4}$,
$x_1+x_2\leq 1$, and 
$x_1\geq 0$, $x_2\geq 0$.

I mean could you please suggest a general method? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its the Gilbert–Johnson–Keerthi (GJK) algorithm, man, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilbert%E2%80%93Johnson%E2%80%93Keerthi_distance_algorithm).